# JSON result containing only one item

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm likely missing something with json and javascript.

```
[{"commentText":"Testing 123","userPosted":"maxfridbe"},
{"commentText":"Testing 23","userPosted":"maxfridbe"}]
```

Sometimes I get multiple responses which works with this code:

```
function(data) 
        {
            var sel = this;

            jQuery.each(data,
                function()
                {
                    sel.append("<li>"+ this.userPosted+ "-" + this.commentText + "</li>");
                });          
        };
```

Sometimes I only get one response which breaks the above code:

```
[{"commentText":"another test again welcom","userPosted":"maxfridbe"}]
```

I know this is because the response is being treated differently than a list.

Looking for the answer to this I get a bit of a runaround.  Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing around with CMS's solution made me realize that data was just a string somehow so:

```
if (!jQuery.isArray(data))  data = eval(data);
```

worked because then the data was an object.  Not sure why when there are multiple results it does an eval for you.

Comment: If your data is just a string, you should use the dataType: 'json' option on your ajax request, or use the getJSON function

Answer (score 7):

In the second example you provide, it seems to be an array with only one item, if it's like that, it should work, but I think that you're getting only a single object like:

```
{"commentText":"another test again welcom","userPosted":"maxfridbe"}
```

If it's a single object [`$.each`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each) iterates over the object properties.

You could check if your `data` variable is not an array using [`$.isArray`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.isArray), and if is not, you can wrap it into a single element array, so the [`$.each`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each) function will still work as expected:

```
//..
if (!jQuery.isArray(data))  data = [data]; // if isn't an array, wrap it

jQuery.each(data, function() {
  sel.append("<li>"+ this.userPosted+ "-" + this.commentText + "</li>");
});
//..
```

Comment: This sounds right to me.  Maxfriebe should pull out firebug and look very carefully at his data.

Comment: Awesome answer! I had the same problem as the OP and this worked like a charm. I had no idea that `each()` would iterate through the properties of an object if only a single object was presented for it to iterate through.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should user some optional parameters in your each() function:

```
function(data) 
    {
        var sel = this;

        jQuery.each(data,
            function(i, item)
            {
                sel.append("<li>"+ item.userPosted+ "-" + item.commentText + "</li>");
            });          
    };
```

using THIS keyword creates confusion in your case

Hope this helps