# jQuery each loop with single object returns "undefined"

Tags: jquery, json

I have a jQuery function that makes a call to an ASP.NET Web API. I know the API returns a client object successfully because I can enter the API url directly and the object info is displayed in XML format in the browser. The JSON data is returned as a collection and jQuery loops through and appends `<option>` elements to a `<select>` element.

What I am having trouble with is how to use jQuery to display the results. The jQuery works fine to display a collection of objects, however if only one object is returned it displays "undefined" for the `<option>` element.

```
   function searchClients() {
      var uri = 'api/clients';
      var searchParam = $('#SearchTerm').val();
      $.getJSON(uri + '/' + searchParam)
        .done(function (data) {
          $('#selSearchResults').show(); // Displays hidden select element
          $('#selSearchResults').html(""); // Clear any pre-existing data in select element
          $.each(data, function (key, item) {
            $('#selSearchResults')
              .append('<option value="' + key + '">' + item.OrgName + ' - ' + item.ID + '</option>');
          })
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
            $('#ErrorMessage').text('Error: ' + err);
        });
    }
```

If the `.each` function receives a single object for `data` will if return undefined? If this is so how does one account for a result that may contain a single object or just one? I thought the `.each` would account for this.

Comment: Then check the returned `data` first whether it's a collection or a single object.

Comment: Or maybe rather, make sure that the endpoint you are requesting the data from always delivers an Array/Object, and not just a single value – the behavior should be consistent.

Comment: Are you sure that `data[1].item.OrgName` has value?
It seems to me that `OrgName` and `ID` are `undefined`

Comment: @WereWolf @CBroe@ - Wont the `.each` iterate with a single object? Does one always have to check to see if an resultant object collection has one or more members before iterating through? I would expect to see this more in examples because with a query one doesn't know how many results may be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! The problem was that a single object was being returned and when this occurs the `each()` function iterates through the properties of the object. The solution was to "wrap" the single object into an array so `each()` would be able to iterate properly. I added this line to my jQuery ...

```
if (!jQuery.isArray(data)) data = [data]; // If a single object is returned, wrap it in an array
```

Here it is in the whole function.

```
function searchClients() {
   var uri = 'api/clients';
   var searchParam = $('#SearchTerm').val();
   $.getJSON(uri + '/' + searchParam)
     .done(function (data) {
       $('#selSearchResults').show(); // Displays hidden select element
       $('#selSearchResults').html(""); // Clear any pre-existing data in select element
       if (!jQuery.isArray(data)) data = [data]; // If a single object is returned, wrap it in an array
       $.each(data, function (key, item) {
         $('#selSearchResults')
           .append('<option value="' + key + '">' + item.OrgName + ' - ' + item.ID + '</option>');
       })
     })
     .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
         $('#ErrorMessage').text('Error: ' + err);
     });
}
```

I found the solution to this problem from the following [SO article - JSON result containing only one item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418400/json-result-containing-only-one-item) and looking at the answer from [@CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445/cms).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe something wrong is coming from your API. 
Check if you actually sending an array, or objects for example.

Assure that your data looks like:

`var data = [
    {ID: 01, OrgName: "Organization1"},
    {ID: 02, OrgName: "Organization2"},
    {ID: 03, OrgName: "Organization3"}
];`

You can play with the data here: http://jsfiddle.net/lcustodio/FBdSj/

Comment: I can confirm that in this case the API is returning a single object. I am just confused as to why the `.each` would not iterate through once even if there is only one object in the collection.