# Calling GET method that return IHttpActionResult from AJAX?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

AJAX works fine with the `GetAll` method that returns `IQueryable`, but with `GetOne`, it doesn't work and return "undefined" to the browser, 
here is the Get method in the `ApiController` class:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Author))]
public IHttpActionResult GetAuthor(int id)
{
    Author author = db.Authors.Find(id);
    if (author == null)
    {
        return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, $"Author with {id} not found."));
    }

    return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, author));
}
```

this is the AJAX function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'api/Authors',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:{id:'1'},
    success: function (data) {
        list.empty();
        $.each(data, function (index, val) {
            var qualifier = val.AuthorId + ' - ' + val.Name;
            list.append('<li>'+qualifier+'</li>')
        });
    }
});
```

Is this because `GetAuthor` returns `IHttpActionResult`?

GetAuthors:

```
public IQueryable<Author> GetAuthors()
{
    return db.Authors;
}
```

Screenshot of the Console window:

[image]

Comment: To check if the response is a valid JSON format (it's what Ajax is expecting here), you can add after success this function `complete: function(data) { console.log(data) }` and check the output. It can be a problem with async or with the returned JSON format itself.

Comment: And can we see the code for GetAll ?

Comment: I added the code, check it out please!]

Comment: Can you try a `return Ok(new { success = true });` instead of `ResponseMessage` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this because `GetAuthor` returns `IHttpActionResult`

**NO!**
The issue is how you are dealing with the response returned from the request.

The example action is returning a single author yet being treated like a collection on the client.

```
function GetData(id) {
    var url = 'api/Authors';
    if(id) url = url + '?id=' + id;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            list.empty();
            if (!jQuery.isArray(data)) data = [data]; // If a single object is returned, wrap it in an array
            $.each(data, function (index, val) {
                var qualifier = val.AuthorId + ' - ' + val.Name;
                list.append('<li>'+qualifier+'</li>')
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: when you debug is the action being executed, and what is the value of the id when debugging? put a break point in the action and check

Comment: Yes, it's executed with both approaches (yours, and mind with using `data`) and the Id is 1 or whatever I pass

Comment: you get the id For both variations?

Comment: Yes.. I added a screenshot of the console window you may want to have a look

Comment: also your action is returning a single author yet you are treating it like a collection on the client

Comment: `each` cannot be used with single object?

Comment: Nope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922798/jquery-each-loop-with-single-object-returns-undefined

Comment: Isn't there a workaround I want to use the same function to return either a collection or single object (if the user enters a value for the `Id`)

Comment: I don't understand. I thought there were two distinct actions being called

Comment: yes, but if I'm using a textbox and the user left it empty the parameterless version will be called, if he enters a value then the url will be appended with the `Id` and the second action called

Comment: That is client side logic that you can have two separate functions called based on whether text box is empty. I updated answer to allow the function that gets back one result to convert it to a list.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed over chat, we confirmed that the answer was a `success`.

However the `data` value was not an array and was returning something equivalent to:

```
{
    AuthorId: 1,
    Book: null,
    Name: "Name here"
}
```

Therefore the following jQuery code for the `success` will be valid:

```
success: function(data){ 
    var qualifier = data.AuthorId + ' - ' + data.Name; 
    list.append('<li>'+qualifier+'</li>'); 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It will work only with single object, I want to use it either with list of object or a single author, based on the user choice

Comment: Then try what @Nkosi suggested before the `$.each` :             `if (!jQuery.isArray(data)) data = [data]; // If a single object is returned, wrap it in an array`